Grafana: Accessing Time Range from API?
I'm attempting to import the currently selected time range in a dashboard (in the upper right) into Python through the API.
From my understanding, the API can only retrieve the JSON of a dashboard, which when accessed via the API contains 'time' which is just the default time range, not the currently selected one. It also looks like it shows the queries my graphs use for InfluxDB, but their time range is just displayed with 'v.timeRangeStart' or 'v.timeRangeStop' rather than the actual value.
Is there any way to access the currently selected and displayed time range?

To be clear, you want to get a value that some random user selected on their dashboard through API?

@markalex I am running Grafana locally so it would only be the current user of that machine that is also using the interface that I want to import it to.
